# Take the value of the selected checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

With a button I intend to take the value of the checkbox to edit a row in the database.

I have my code organized as follows. First I start by creating my table like this:

HTML:

```
<table id="tabfor" class="table">
    <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <th class="table__heading"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></FONT></i></th>
            <th class="table__heading"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">Registo</FONT></th>
            <th class="table__heading"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">Fornecedor</FONT></th>
            <th class="table__heading"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">Nif</FONT></th>
            <th class="table__heading"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">Contato</FONT></th>
            <th class="table__heading"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">Morada</FONT></th> 
            <th class="table__heading"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">Postal</FONT></th>
            <th class="table__heading"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">Email</FONT></th>
            <th class="table__heading"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">Colaboorador</FONT></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I dynamically create the table:

```
$.getJSON('perfilfor.php', function (data) {

$('#tabfor').dataTable().fnDestroy();
var linha = ``; 

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
   Id = data[i][0];
   DataRegisto = data[i][1];
   Fornecedor = data[i][2];
   Nif = data[i][3];
   Contato = data[i][4];
   Morada = data[i][5];
   Postal = data[i][6];
   Email = data[i][7];
   Nome = data[i][8];



      linha += `<tr class="table__row">
       <td  class="table__content" data-heading="Atualizar"><input type="checkbox" name="update" id="update" value="${ Id }"></td>     
       <td class="table__content" data-heading="Registo"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">${ DataRegisto }</FONT></td> 
       <td class="table__content" data-heading="Nome"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">${ Fornecedor }</FONT></td>
       <td class="table__content" data-heading="Nif"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">${ Nif }</FONT></td>
       <td class="table__content" data-heading="Contato"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">${ Contato }</FONT></td> 
       <td class="table__content" data-heading="Morada"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">${ Morada }</FONT></td>
       <td class="table__content" data-heading="CEP"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">${ Postal }</FONT></td> 
       <td class="table__content" data-heading="Email"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">${ Email }</FONT></td>
       <td class="table__content" data-heading="Colaborador"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">${ Nome }</FONT></td>       
       </tr>`; 
    }
    $("#tabfor tbody").html(linha);
});
```

In this table in the first `td` I create an input `checkbox` to get the id of the line I want to edit.

Now I created a button to edit as follows:

```
<button href="s7" class="btn btn-warning caixa btn-show close-sidebar upd_forn" data-element="#minhaDiv6" style="float:right;"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square fa-5x taman" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<br>
    <h4>Editar</h4>
    <h4>Fornecedor</h4>
</button>
```

Now in js I intend to take the checkbox value that I created in the previous table. I'm trying this way:

```
$(document).on('click', '.upd_forn', function(){ 

   var updf = $("#update").is(":checked") ? $("#update").val() : '';

   $.ajax({  
        url:"updforn.php",  
        method:"POST",
        cache: false,               
        data:{updf:updf},               
        dataType:"json",  
        success:function(data){
            
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
                       
               Id = data[i][0];
               Fornecedor = data[i][1];
               Nif = data[i][2];
               Contato = data[i][3];
               Morada = data[i][4];
               Postal = data[i][5];
               Email = data[i][6];
               Colaborador = data[i][7];
            
             $('#Idf').val(Id);
             $('#Fornecedor1').val(Fornecedor);
             $('#Nif2').val(Nif);
             $('#Contato2').val(Contato);
             $('#Morada2').val(Morada);
             $('#Postal2').val(Postal);
             $('#Email3').val(Email);
             $('#minhaDiv6').show();
             $('#minhaDiv1').hide();
            }
        }

    });
});
```

But this way it only returns the value, if you select the checkbox of the first row that returns from the database table.
Selecting one of the other lines no longer returns the line id.

Comment: `+= "id='update'"` on every row - IDs must be unique `$("#update")` will always give you the first one

Comment: @reedomn-m And how can I always be exclusive? Do I use a class instead of the id?

Comment: @ikiK Can you give an example how it would look?

Comment: Give the checkbox a class `class='update'` then find the one that's checked, probably: `var updf = $(".update:checked").first().value`

Comment: From a UX perspective, *checkbox* on each row then a separate button to edit/view makes no sense - put the edit/view button on the row directly or use a radio button.  What if the user ticks multiple rows before clicking the button?  What's it supposed to do?

Comment: Oh you are right i need my coffee...  @freedomn-m

Comment: @freedomn-m I already replaced the checkbox for radio the input, but it still doesn't work. I already tried with the solutions that I talked about, but it still doesn't work. I intended to use it this way, because visually for the user it looks better

Comment: font tags are obsolete and should not be used

Comment: @Pete  What sources are you referring to that are obsolete?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#font

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using the `querySelector`, which in this way takes the id of the selected radio input.

complete code:

```
var updf = document.querySelector('input[name="update"]:checked').value;
```